# Flutter generates a lot of android permissions not declared in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, flutter, android-permissions

I am uploading an app to Google Play Store in Internal Testing.
Google reported an error and asked me to declare the "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" permission in the AndroidManifest.xml file, but my app doesn't use this permission. There are also a lot of other permissions listed in the list.
[image]

This is the pubspec.yaml file.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_cupertino_localizations: ^1.0.1

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  path_provider: ^2.0.8
  equatable: ^2.0.3
  excel:
    git: https://github.com/justkawal/excel
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  connectivity_plus: ^2.2.0
  http_parser: ^4.0.0
  dio: ^4.0.0
  get: ^4.6.1
  hive: ^2.2.3
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
  shimmer: ^2.0.0
  another_flushbar: ^1.10.28
  flutter_svg: ^1.0.3
  cached_network_image: ^3.1.0
  image_picker: ^0.8.1+4
  flutter_image_compress: ^1.0.0
  geolocator: ^9.0.1
  geocoding: ^2.0.2
  tutorial_coach_mark: ^1.2.1
  jiffy: ^5.0.0
  file_picker: ^5.0.1
  permission_handler: ^10.0.0
  package_info_plus: ^1.4.2
  json_annotation: ^4.7.0
  control_style: ^0.0.2
  timezone: ^0.8.0
  flutter_native_timezone: ^2.0.0
  rxdart: ^0.27.5
  assets_audio_player:
    path: plugins/assets-audio-player
  flutter_device_type: ^0.4.0
  fading_edge_scrollview: ^3.0.0
  awesome_notifications: ^0.7.3
  intl: ^0.17.0
  url_launcher: ^6.1.6
  flutter_phoenix: ^1.1.0
  video_player: ^2.4.7
  simple_shadow: ^0.3.0
  timer_controller: ^1.0.0
  change_app_package_name: ^1.1.0
  firebase_core: ^2.5.0
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.0.12
  photo_view: ^0.14.0
```

I checked the libraries used in the project but still not found these permissions.
I want to know how do I remove these permissions from my app.

Thanks so much!

Comment: add your pubspec.yaml so that we can see which packages are you using.

Comment: Thank you! I just updated the pubspec.yaml file in the question.

Comment: Because your package is taking this permission so your apk is taking those permission

Comment: I suggest you to move the development dependencies from  dependencies: to dev_dependencies:  first then try again (for example change_app_package_name)